# jquery load function show content two time

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a page with name load.php with this content:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("a").click(function () {          
                $("#mehdi").load(this.href, function(){
                 });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>

<a href="load.php?Name=mehdi"> click for load ajax</a>
<div id="mehdi">

<?php
    $db = new grid();
    $db->show();


    ?>
```

when i click on `a tag` the page post to `dbload.php` with this content:

```
class grid
{
    function show()
    {
        echo"<div id = 'show'>";
        if(isset( $_GET["Name"] ))
            echo "done";
        else
            echo "Not done";
            echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

when i see the page with browser it's like this:

when i click on `a tag` it's like this:
[image]

[image]

my problem is that the second link is added to page automatically. what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `<a href="load.php?Name=mehdi"> click for load ajax</a>` within `<div id="mehdi">`. That way it will get replaced when you call `load`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a").click(function () {          
            $("#mehdi").load(this.href, function(){
             });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="mehdi">
    <a href="load.php?Name=mehdi"> click for load ajax</a>

<?php
    $db = new grid();
    $db->show();
?>
```

That will fix your issue, but you should really consider loading a different page through your ajax call. Perhaps `ajax.php`. This is because everything inside of `load.php` is getting re-rendered inside of itself. So, after 1 ajax call this:

```
<div id="mehdi">
  <a href="load.php?Name=mehdi"> click for load ajax</a>
  not done
</div>
```

will become nested with this:

```
<div id="mehdi">
  <div id="mehdi">
    <a href="load.php?Name=mehdi"> click for load ajax</a>
    not done
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("a").click(function () { 
e.preventDefault()
...
```